# Unable to Push to GitHub with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github, push

Android Studio can not push my project to GitHub with the following error:
`Push failed: Failed with error: unable to access https://github.com/MY_PROJECT_NAME: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain`
What could it possibly mean? If anyone faced the problem, maybe he could share a solution?
Grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be several causes, but I'll believe you has correct username/password and access rights.

My recommendation is to install [Github for Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) and fix `https` url to `SSH` url.

Android Studio git function will work same as Github for Desktop(let say *GD* afterwards) if both program loads same working directory, so if you can pull/push at GD, then you can do the same thing on Android Studio.

1. When you install GD, open your project directory (File > Add local repository). If it fails to push at GD, Open `Repository` menu > `Repository settings`
2. In repository settings dialog, you can see `https://...` url. Change it to `git@...` just like below url gives. GitHub allows you to use HTTPS and SSH. But HTTPS did not allow to push but SSH does by your local machine setup. The `git@...` url will be shown if you click the upper-right location `Use HTTPS` text, which is from your original github project.

[image]

3. If above remedy did not work, your machine certificate or git setup need to be fixed. Let me leave this remedy to another answerer.